# EF Code First Migrations creating extra Column when Extending the Identity Role Class

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, entity-framework-migrations

I opened VS2013 and created an empty MVC project with identity 1, I wanted to extend Identity Role Class, adding an extra field to AspNetRoles, so I added this class to Models Folder:

```
  public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole
    {
        public ApplicationRole() : base() { }
        public ApplicationRole(string name, string title)
            : base(name)
        {
            this.Title = title;
        }
        public virtual string Title { get; set; }
    }
```

then in PowerShell > enable-migrations>add-migration mig1  and it created below class:

```
public partial class mig1 : DbMigration
    {
        public override void Up()
        {
            CreateTable(
                "dbo.AspNetRoles",
                c => new
                    {
                        Id = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
                        Name = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 256),
                        Title = c.String(),
                        Discriminator = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),  // The rogue column
                    })
                .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
                .Index(t => t.Name, unique: true, name: "RoleNameIndex");    
        {
         //Another tables         
   {
```

but as you can see migration created an extra column (Discriminator) that I don't know what is that.

it wasn't what I want so I commented it and for seeding in configuration class I added this codes:

```
protected override void Seed(another.Models.ApplicationDbContext context)
        {

            if (!context.Roles.Any(r => r.Name == "AppAdmin"))
            {
                var store = new RoleStore<ApplicationRole>(context);
                var manager = new RoleManager<ApplicationRole>(store);
                var role = new ApplicationRole { Name = "AppAdmin", Title = "Admin" };

                // Create: Create a role.    
                manager.Create(role);
            }
            if (!context.Roles.Any(r => r.Name == "Customer"))
            {
                var store = new RoleStore<ApplicationRole>(context);
                var manager = new RoleManager<ApplicationRole>(store);
                var role = new ApplicationRole { Name = "Customer",Title="usualuser" };

            // Create: Create a role.    
            manager.Create(role);
        }
    }
```

then in PowerShell > update-database, and it threw an exception:
"An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid column name 'Discriminator'"

EDITED: this my context

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("ShopDB", throwIfV1Schema: false)
        {
        }

        public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
        {
            return new ApplicationDbContext();
        }
    }
```

Comment: The `Discriminator` column is usually created when you have a table per hierarchy setup. What does your context look like?

Comment: I added the Context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your context doesn't specify that you are using your custom role class so Entity Framework scans the project for any classes that inherit from the base `IdentityRole` class and assumes that you may want to use TPH (table per hierarchy) where it's possible to store both `IdentityRole` and `ApplicationRole` objects in the same `DbSet`. To do this, it adds a `Discriminator` column to distinguish what the type is.

To fix this, your context should inherit from the [other `IdentityDbContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/web-frameworks/dn613255%28v%3dvs.108%29) that allows you to specify the types. For example:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : 
    IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, string, 
        IdentityUserLogin, IdentityUserRole, IdentityUserClaim>
{
    //Snip
}
```